# Getting specified range of an array in Nunjucks

Tags: javascript, templating, nunjucks

```
{% set array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] %}
```

I want a range of this array. Just like this:

`[2,3,4,5]`

In JavaScript, it is so easy to be done with the `slice` method. But in Nunjucks, `slice` works different. I don't know how to take a range of this array.

Comment: `{% set arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] %} {{ arr.slice(2,6) }}`? Or you can use [range](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#range-start-stop-step).

Comment: It doesn't work for this case. That `slice` fn doesn't work like JS `slice`.

Comment: What does it  return for you?

Comment: That `slice` is js-`slice`. Nunjucks `slice` has another syntax - `{{ arr | slice(3) }}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It doesn't work for this case. That `slice` doesn't work like JS `slice`.

Actually it *is* the JS `slice`, and we can use it directly in NJK templates.

Note the **dot syntax**:

```
{% set array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] %}

{{ array.slice(2, 5) }}
```

Output (3rd to 5th items):

```
c,d,e
```

---

What can be confusing is that Nunjucks has its own `slice`, which is a totally unrelated filter.

Note the **pipe syntax**:

```
{% for items in array | slice(2, 5) %}
  {{ items }}
{% endfor %}
```

Output (2 slices with the shorter slice padded by "5"):

```
a,b,c
d,e,5
```